# maxifs returning 00/00/1900 as date for blank date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want latest dates corresponding to each unique ID mentioned in sheet1. When no date is mentioned against an ID , I am getting 00/01/1900 as the latest date instead of blank. How to fix this

Sheet1 (input data sheet)

```
     A     B
   2 ID    Date1 
   3 ID1  20/11/2020
   4 ID2  18/10/2019
   5 ID1  29/01/2018
   6 ID2  10/10/2021
   7 ID3
```

Formula used in sheet2 (to caluclate latest date for each ID)

```
     A          B
   2 IDSheet2  Latestdate 
   3 ID2        =maxifs('Sheet1'!B:B,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"="&A2)
   4 ID1
   5 ID3
```

**OUTPUT obtained**

```
    A          B
   2 IDSheet2  Latestdate 
   3 ID2        10/10/2021
   4 ID1        20/11/2020
   5 ID3        00/01/1900  (want a blank here)
```

Issue:

I am getting 00/01/1900 as date when there is a blank date corresponding to an ID. How to get blank against ID3 here for instance instead of 00/01/1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the reciprocal or the  reciprocal:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/maxifs('Sheet1'!B:B,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"="&A2)),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Two current options:**

1. **IF formula**
   This lets you check if the max would be 0

   =IF(MAXIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!$A:$A,A2)=0, "", MAXIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!$A:$A,A2))
2. **Cell formatting**
   On the relevant cells, change cell formatting (CTRL+1), choose custom and enter `dd/mm/yyyy;;`
   Doing this requires no formula change.
3. (bonus for future Excel release - IF with LET)
   In an upcoming release there will be the LET function where you only define the variable once for improved performance and easier reading.  The formula would be: =LET(max_value,MAXIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!$A:$A,A2),IF(max_value=0,"",max_value))

Answer (score 1):

Try it

if(day(maxifs('Sheet1'!B:B,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"="&A2)<1,"",maxifs('Sheet1'!B:B,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"="&A2))